# How to put Google Tag Manager code to Hubspot

Tags: google-tag-manager, hubspot

I tried to place Google Tag Manager code via individual page settings as for their instruction on https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-general/how-do-i-add-the-google-tag-manager-code-to-my-hubspot-pages

[image: Hubspot Instructions]

But Google wants it to be placed just below the `<body>` tags. So I tried placing it using a custom module but it is being wrapped by a `<span>` tags which google doesn't like.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put script part of GTM code in head and noscript part in body (footer in your case). It will work.

Comment: You sir rock! Even Hubspot support couldn't figure what to do. Thanks much!